# Не позиционируемая панель скрол бара

Tags: jquery

В общем проблема фиктивная, даже проблемой то не назвать, можно сделать как в ie: скролл есть всегда, активный - если есть прокрутка, и неактивный если её нету.
Ну ко мне пристал заказчик и просит сделать как в вконтакте. Т.е сролл не позиционируется на странице, и при его появлении страница не дергается.
Как можно это сделать с помощью `jQuery` не подскажите? Может есть какой-нибудь плагин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писал в комментарии, теперь с поправками. Пример можно [посмотреть тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/gFfgz/6/), а пояснения расшифрую в ответе.

```
var detectShit = {
    Version: function() {
        var version = 999;
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1){
            version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
            return version;
        }
    }
};

function scrollСompensation(){
    // IE7 уже имеет поле для скроллбара, посему - для него отмена
    if(detectShit.Version() <= 7) return false;

    // если скроллбара нет, то величины равные и сравниваем их ниже, 
    // дабы проверить наличие скролла
    var dH = $(document).height(); // высота документа
    var wH = $(window).height(); // высота окна

    // поправка для IE8 (вычислил вручную, посему не уверен на 100%)
    if (detectShit.Version() == 8) {
        wH += 4;
    }
    // сравниваем высоту окна и документа
    if(dH > wH){
        // устанавливаем "поправку на скролл"
        $(wrapper).css('padding-left', 8.5);
    } else {
        // или "0", если скролла нет
        $(wrapper).css('padding-left', 0);
    }
}

// остается вызывать эту функцию при загрузке документа или при динамическом изменении контента
$(window).load(scrollСompensation);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/gFfgz/4/ посмотрите, наверное какая-то недоработка - при появлении скролла без кнопки (меняем высоту фрейма)"поправка" не происходит.

Comment: @eicto, поправка для IE8? Вполне возможно. jsFiddle восьмом  у меня грузиться отказывается, а при тестировании на локалке - вроде бы проблем не возникает. Хотя, и тут я не уверен до конца, т.к. осел у меня девятый, а восьмой имитируется через переключение режимов. И насколько точна эта имитация - я даже не знаю.

P.S. Т.к. с версии jQuery 2.0 вообще собираются убрать поддержку старых ослов, то не исключено, что придется эту же задачу глобально переделывать... если кому-то захочется над этим заморачиваться ))

Comment: нет, в хроме не работает, "дергается" скролл, я так думаю только кастомным баром можно решить, или подвесить фэйковый див со скроллом с абсолютными координатами.

Comment: Да, есть такая буква. Вот [так будет точнее](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/gFfgz/6/).

Comment: :) почти, test case: делаем текста поменьше, запускаем, показываем текст, тащим границу фрейма вверх/вниз (так чтобы скролл появился). http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/gFfgz/7/ вот это почти чинит проблему, только все равно немного дергается.

Comment: Отличный скрипт.
Я так понел он просто двигает контент на ширину скролла?
Т.е поэтому контейнер врап и не дергаеться?
Один вопрос, а что если скролл будет маковский? он же по идее по ширине меньше ( Щас попробую проверить, просто портайбл сафари не помню куда закинул ).
И ещё Скиньте свой номер вмз, на пиво вам скину. Спасибо за решение

Comment: @alexland, по поводу стопроцентной кроссбраузерности - естественно не уверен. А по поводу "*на пиво*" - спс, но не надо ))